# hand writing recognition in c# metro style app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, handwriting

I am developing a note taking application. I want a user to write anything on canvas with InkManager of "Windows.UI.Input.Inking". Then I
want to display it as text onto canvas and then I want to save those recognized text in either text or image format.

I have checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208524) documentation, but still I am confused how to start. How can I get ink strokes onto canvas and how can I recognize that ? Please anyone can guide me ? I need it ASAP for my app.

I have tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
private async void Recognize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<InkRecognitionResult> x = await _inkManager.RecognizeAsync(InkRecognitionTarget.All);
    IReadOnlyList<String> text;
    foreach (InkRecognitionResult i in x)
    {
        text = i.GetTextCandidates();
        res.Text = text.First();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any output, I just debug the program and checked the value of "text", but it is not showing.

Comment: You're overwriting text each time. Maybe just do a System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.GetTextCandidates()) to see the actual results printed out in the debugger. Maybe the last candidate is empty.

Comment: finally I got some output i have added one text block (x:Name = res) and printed output on textblock, but still it can't recognize space (" ")

PS : I have update source in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution myself

```
    IReadOnlyList<String> text;
    string finalt = "";  //for space
    private async void Recognize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<InkRecognitionResult> x = await _inkManager.RecognizeAsync(InkRecognitionTarget.All);
        foreach (InkRecognitionResult i in x)
        {
            text = i.GetTextCandidates();
            finalt += " " + text[0];
            res.Text = finalt;  //res is the x:Key for the text block
        }
    }
```

One more [solution](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/InkPen-sample-in-CSharp-189ce853) and one more *better* [solution](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Input-Ink-sample-12876398)